# Lync Client: How to Sign-in and Send Message

Tags: .net, console-application, lync, office-2013, lync-client-sdk

Here is what I need to do:

I need to build a console app that signs in (not using current user or lync session) to a Lync Server and send a message to a specific contact (userUri). That is all.

However, every time I use `Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient()` , it seems to return the current session. I've already been able to send a message, so the only issue is to sign in without using the current user/session.

How do I setup a new one?

Another weird thing I noticed: I mentioned that I was able to send a message through the console app with my current session (a message is sent to a colleague of mine and displayed). However, when I get the `SignInConfiguration` from `LyncClient.SignInConfiguration`, the UserName property is blank when I assume it's supposed to show my username/userAndDomain.

Code below:

```
lyncClient = Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient();               

                if (lyncClient == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to obtain client interface");
                }
                if (lyncClient.InSuppressedMode == true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lync is uninitialized");
                }

                if (lyncClient.State == ClientState.SignedIn)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lync is signed in");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Lync is NOT signed in");
                }

                SignInConfiguration config = lyncClient.SignInConfiguration;

                internalUrl = config.InternalServerUrl;
                externalUrl = config.ExternalServerUrl;
                signedInFromIntranet = config.SignedInFromIntranet.ToString();
                signedInAvailability = config.SignInAsAvailability.ToString();
                signedInAutoRetry = config.SignInAutoRetry.ToString();
                signedInUser = config.UserName;

                Console.WriteLine("Internal Url: " + internalUrl);
                Console.WriteLine("External Url: " + externalUrl);
                Console.WriteLine("Signed-in from Intranet: " + signedInFromIntranet);
                Console.WriteLine("Signed-in as availability: " + signedInAvailability);
                Console.WriteLine("Signed-in as auto-retry: " + signedInAutoRetry);
                Console.WriteLine("Signed-in User: " + signedInUser);

                conversation = lyncClient.ConversationManager.AddConversation();
                conversation.AddParticipant(lyncClient.ContactManager.GetContactByUri(recipientUri));

                if (((Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.InstantMessageModality)conversation.Modalities[Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ModalityTypes.InstantMessage]).CanInvoke(Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ModalityAction.SendInstantMessage))
                {
                    ((Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.InstantMessageModality)conversation.Modalities[Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation.ModalityTypes.InstantMessage]).BeginSendMessage(
                        message,
                        null,
                        null
                        );
                }
```

Comment: Have you considered using UCWA to connect to your Lync Server instead of the Lync Client SDK? Lync Client SDK doesn't actually allow you much stand-alone functionality as it requires a Lync Client.

Answer (score 0):

Please Check following link, this explains for Lync 2013, but I am sure same is available with 2010 API also.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lync/jj937241.aspx

Comment: thanks, i've seen that already and had some problems implementing that on a console app. appreciate your reply though :)

Comment: I have actually implemented Lync SDK and got this scenario rectified, I"ll send you the code tdy